# how to create marker like abovebar and belowbar via trading-view library(pinejs)

Tags: javascript, tradingview-api

Here I creating marks in custom indicator [tradingview charting library (pinejs)], I want to add position in marker, how to do it?

Here I want to add position in marker, like abovebar, belowbar etc

This is the code

```
getTimescaleMarks: (symbolInfo,startDate,endDate,onDataCallback,resolution) => {
    var arr = [
            {
                
                id: "marker-1",
                time: 1683158400000 / 1000, // timestamp in seconds
                // position: "aboveBar",
                color: "green",
                // shape: "circle",
                text: "My Marker",
                label: "B",
                labelFontColor: "white",
                minSize: 20
        },
    ]
    onDataCallback(arr);
    console.log("-----running");
    }
```

but marker is shown at the very buttom of the chart for that specific date, but I want to keep its position belowbar, how to do it